# Artin's Algebra, Proposition 4.6.10: Why is $\Lambda=[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}A[\mathbf{B}]$ rather than the other way around?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In his *Algebra* pp.118-119, Artin proves what is stated in the title of my question, roughly as follows:

> Given a $2\times2$ real matrix $A$ with two eigenvectors $v_1, v_2$, linearly independent, then $A$ is diagonalizable: we may form a basis $\mathbf{B}=(v_1, v_2)$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$, and the matrix relating the standard basis $\mathbf{E}$ to this basis $\mathbf{B}$ is $P=[\mathbf{B}]$, i.e. the matrix obtained by arranging  the elements of $\mathbf{B}$ as columns. Then the diagonalization of $A$ is $\Lambda=[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}A[\mathbf{B}]$. Since $\Lambda= P^{-1}AP$ and $P=[\mathbf{B}]$.

But if in general, $\mathbf{B}^\prime=\mathbf{B}P$ means $A^\prime= P^{-1}AP$, ($\mathbf{B}^\prime$ and $\mathbf{B}$ being bases of the same vector space, and $A^\prime$ and $A$ the respective matrices of some same linear operator $T$), the equation should rather be $\Lambda=Q^{-1}AQ=[\mathbf{B}]A[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}$, for in my understanding, $\Lambda$ is "as if" the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{E}$, which is related to $\mathbf{B}$ by $Q=[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}$, i.e. $\mathbf{E}= \mathbf{B}Q= \mathbf{B}[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}$.

**Note:** In the author's example

> $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 3 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} $, and $P=[\mathbf{B}]=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $, $P^{-1}=\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $

which means it makes no difference whether $P$ or $P^{-1}$ comes first, but I suspect that's simply a coincidence, which unfortunately renders it impossible to tell which formula is the correct one.

**Update:** Guess I have found where I went wrong: $A$ is given, so to speak, as the matrix of some operator $T$ w.r.t. the standard basis $\mathbf{E}$, when we  determines $\mathbf{B}$ from $A$, we are constructing another basis w.r.t which the matrix of $T$ is diagonal, for $[\mathbf{B}]$ is (sloppily) \begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 \\0&1\end{bmatrix} w.r.t itself.

Comment: What do you mean "other way around"? what is the concrete question?

Comment: Why $\Lambda =Q^{-1}AQ$?

Comment: @MadhanKumar 'for in my understanding, $\Lambda$ is "as if" the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{E}$, which is related to $\mathbf{B}$ by $Q=[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}$, i.e. $\mathbf{E}= \mathbf{B}Q= \mathbf{B}[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}$.' In other words, I thought $\Lambda$ is simply some $A^\prime$.

Comment: @CésarVB why isn't it $\Lambda=[\mathbf{B}]A[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}$?

Comment: $\Lambda $ is a diagonal matrix right? If you change basis,diagonality may not be there.

Comment: @C_Arietta_C when you say "the equation should rather be $\Lambda = Q^{-1}AQ = [B]A[B]^{-1}$", this is true if indeed $Q = [B]^{-1}$, because using the fact that [the inverse of an inverse matrix is the matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161785/proof-the-inverse-of-the-inverse-matrix-is-the-matrix). If $Q = [B]^{-1}$, then $Q^{-1} = ([B]^{-1})^{-1} = [B]$ and this proves that indeed if $\Lambda = B^{-1}AB$, then $\Lambda = QAQ^{-1}$. I don't know if this answers the question.

Comment: @MadhanKumar Well, $\Lambda$ is indeed diagonal, but it’s the outcome of diagonalization of $A$, viz, we are dealing with a *diagonalizable* matrix $A$, and all we know for sure is that, sloppily speaking, there exists some basechange matrix *from* $A$ *to* $\Lambda$, call it $Q$, etc.

Comment: @CésarVB Not exactly, we have $A$ in the first place, and  the corresponding basis $\mathbf{B}$. To turn $A$ into a diagonal matrix, we need some $\mathbf{B}^\prime=\mathbf{E}$ , (if I’m not mistaken, that a diagonal matrix comes with a standard basis seems to be something trivial for the author), there is a basechange matrix relating $\mathbf{B}$ with $\mathbf{B}^\prime$, namely Q=$[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}$ , for $\mathbf{B}^\prime=\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{B}[\mathbf{B}]^{-1}$, ergo the last but one paragraph of the question.

Comment: @CésarVB But it turns out that I *am* mistaken, unfortunately… plz check out the update.

Comment: @ Never mind, no such $Q$ other than $[\mathbf{B]}$ is needed, my mistake ;P.